# How to scroll the page body to the specific location by element id in Magento2 CMS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, magento2.2

I want to open a product tab on the product page with a click of an anchor tag in Magento2. The Magento2 CMS version is 2.2.5, below is the code:

```js
require([
  'jquery'
], function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mor-link').on('click', function(event) {
      // Prevent URL change
      console.log('clicked');
      event.preventDefault();
      // `this` is the clicked <a> tag
      $('[data-toggle="switch"][href="' + this.hash + '"]').trigger('click');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<a id="read_more" class="mor-link" href="#new3.tab">Read More...</a>
```

.

**So here I want to open the FAQ's product tab with scroll down the page body. You can check on my website as well: https://example.com/staging/tinted-sunscreen.html
My script is working fine to open the FAQ's tab but the page body is not scrolling down to the desired element location. Please let me know, how I can achieve this thing.
I just want to open FAQ's tab after the click on the 'Readmore...' link and page body jump to that place.**

Thanks in Advance, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) method inside your click handler:

```
$('.mor-link').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('[data-toggle="switch"][href="' + this.hash + '"]').trigger('click');
  document.getElementById("tab-label-new3.tab").scrollIntoView();
});
```

Comment: Hey @ariel, can you please elaborate where I use you're given the above code in my script. After the trigger or maybe some changes. So could you please send here the full code as I am new to jquery.

Comment: Just place it inside the click handler

Comment: that's great it is working. But it will jump to the 2nd no. question why not it will be stopped at the starting of the tab content. Please check this once.

Comment: Please read the documentation on scrollIntoView https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: Currently, I am using these attributes with scrollInto function document.getElementById("new3.tab").scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "start", inline: "start"});, but still, it is not stopped at the starting of the FAQ's tab content portion. Please suggest the best one, thanks.

Comment: Change to `document.getElementById("tab-label-new3.tab").scrollIntoView();`. The problem is your site have that floating menu, so it scrolls under it.

Comment: it still jumps to the same place. This will also not stopped at the starting of the faq tab content.